# vim: grep/vimgrep on quickfix window and error:E499

Tags: vim, grep, vimgrep

I want to search and list patterns in a file, so I can use `vimgrep pattern %`
Now this will create a quickfix window, if we type `:cw` or `:cwindow` it opens the search results.

Now I want to grep or vimgrep on this quickfix window, to filter further.

eg:
filename: tmp

```
IRQ test A - pass    
REG_WR test A - pass
REG_RD A:0 pass    
REG_RD A:1 fail    
REG_RD A:2 pass    
REG_RD test A - fail    
IRQ test B - pass    
REG_WR test B - pass  

REG_RD B:0 pass    
REG_RD B:1 pass    
REG_RD B:2 pass    
REG_RD test B - pass
```

Now first I use **vimgrep test %** to get the below in quickfix window.

```
tmp|1 col 9| IRQ test A - pass    
tmp|2 col 12| REG_WR test A - pass
tmp|6 col 12| REG_RD test A - fail    
tmp|7 col 9| IRQ test B - pass    
tmp|8 col 12| REG_WR test B - pass  
tmp|13 col 12| REG_RD test B - pass
```

Now immediately i want to search for all passed tests.

If  give `:vimgrep pass %` on quickfix window, it states that,

> e499:empty filename for '%' or '#', only works with ":p:h"

I'm now saving this results to temporary file and then grepping over it, Is there a easy solution?

My Gvim: IM - Vi IMproved 7.2 (2008 Aug 9, compiled Jun  6 2019 12:19:18)

Comment: Since in all matches, test occurs before pass, you could do a `vimgrep` again with `:vimgrep test.*pass %` or `:vimgrep test.*pass$ %`. This is probably the most intuitive way to fo about this, you start with a basic pattern and then enhance and fine-tune the pattern to get *exactly* the matches that you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the `Cfilter` command to be of great use:

```
" load this plugin that ships with vim in a package
packadd cfilter
vimgrep ...
Cfilter pass
```

Comment: This is really neat! But isn't `packadd` a vim 8+ feature?

Comment: Yeah, you need at least 8 and possible 8.1 or 8.2 @Harish

Comment: Yes my version do not support this, also I dont have enough permission to install plugins, so any methods without installing any pluggins ( adding contents in vimrc is fine) would be good.